# Can the Spring Framework be used in android applications?

Tags: java, android, spring, dependency-injection

I am writing a android application which requires dependency injection in the data access API the application will need (I am implementing this API). I don't want to write the dependency injection manually. Therefore, I was thinking of using Spring. I realize that there are two versions of spring. A regular version and a android version. Can the regular version be used in the android application cause I just want the dependency injection functionality and already have the files.

Comment: "...and already have the files." -- Are you saying you would choose which library to use because you don't want to take the time to download the other jar files?

Comment: Yes, I just want to use those jar files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't. Spring is a heavy weight server-side framework that is not optimized for Android. The have some Android libraries, but those are for specific things like REST. If you need DI, use an Android framework such as [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/).

Comment: "Spring is a heavy weight". Have you done profiling of Spring Boot, or is an anecdotal belief?

Comment: Nowadays, dagger2, hilt and koin are the mainstream DI systems.

Answer (score 9):

If you need DI **and** Spring, please give **RoboSpring** a try. I have ported the Spring Framework to Android and tweaked the performance significantly! From the description:

RoboSpring is a (real) port of the Spring Framework to the Android platform. Additionally it offers preliminary support for functionality introduced by RoboGuice like injecting View references into Activities and more. RoboSpring is based on version 3.1.0 RELEASE of Spring's **core**, **beans**, **context** and **aop** components. It offers the following functionality:

- Configure application components with a Spring configuration file
  (XML)
- Autowire your Android components with beans from the Spring application context.
- Inject the Android application context into your Spring Beans.
- Inject views into Activities.
- … and more

Please see here: https://github.com/dthommes/RoboSpring

[image: RoboSpring - Inversion of Control for Android]

Comment: This project hasn't been maintained in about 6 years, so keep scrolling. This answer really should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the dependency injection only. You may choose some lightweight framework like google guice.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has libraries for android but its for efficiently doing REST communication with some OAuth the detailed information is available here [spring-android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) and the developers of spring advocate using RoboGuice for DI you can read about it from [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/26/clean-code-with-android/), for hardcore dependency injection its [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) which is by far the best out there.